# Let $L_1$ be a DCFL and $L_2$ be recursive language. Is $L_1 \cap L_2$ a DCFL?

Tags: formal-languages

Let $L_1$ be a DCFL and $L_2$ be recursive language. Is $L_1\cap L_2$ a DCFL?

According to me the intersection should be a Recursive language. However the answer given is DCFL. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Textbook, lecture notes,...?

Comment: I think I have got the answer. Let's suppose $L_2$ is DCFL(since every DCFL is recursive). Now we know that the intersection of two DCFL is not DCFL. Hence the intersection cannot be DCFL.